Updating Fuse when current version has dependancies
I am trying to install the ifuse package from the libimobiledevice project and its failing because it requires fuse3. My system is not allowing me to install fuse3 because of dependencies on fuse2. Below is the output of my dilemma. Is there anyway to upgrade to fuse3 without breaking everything?.
sudo apt-get install fuse
[sudo] password for trinsic: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pop-desktop : PreDepends: pop-de-gnome but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: flatpak but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gvfs-fuse but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

My current version of fuse is:
apt show fuse
Package: fuse
Version: 2.9.9-5ubuntu3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 117 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libfuse2 (= 2.9.9-5ubuntu3), adduser, mount (>= 2.19.1), sed (>= 4)
Homepage: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki
Download-Size: 27.0 kB
APT-Sources: http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Filesystem in Userspace
 Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE) is a simple interface for userspace programs to
 export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel. It also aims to provide a
 secure method for non privileged users to create and mount their own filesystem
 implementations.


The solution was to install the dev version of fuse3
sudo apt-get install libfuse3-dev


https://askubuntu.com/a/1513745/289138 - for the interested.
